# Xcode: code coverage percentage

Tags: xcode, xcode7, xctest

Any of you knows how can I get percentage of code coverage in Xcode?. Right now I only see the bars:

[image]

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, the code coverage overview in Xcode is really bad. If you do not use Xcode server to test your projects the only way to obtain the percentage is by mouse over each bar.

[image]

If you use Xcode server you will see the percentage for every device type in a table.

Answer (score 3):

Hover over on top of the first row with the .app. It will tell you the calculated percentage

Answer (score 3):

Just some clarification on where to find these numbers in Xcode 10:

1. Run your tests and navigate to the Test navigator
2. Right click on the test and select "Jump to Report"

[image]

3. Next to your target you should see "Test", right click on that, then select "Coverage"
   [image]
4. Test Coverage info is then shown

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure to have "Gather coverage for" is enabled in the edit scheme:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this question the percentage is show in Xcode now (currently 9.3).

[image: coverage]